# How to configure domain name in apache2 server?

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models

I have deployed  two Django  sites using Apache2, that can can be access through these links given bellow

```
http://93.188.167.63/cholera/
http://93.188.167.63:8080/pep_learn/
```

This is my "000-default.conf" file.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        Alias /static /home/myproject/DATAPLO/static
        <Directory /home/myproject/DATAPLO/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        <Directory /home/myproject/trytable>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/myproject:/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/trytable/wsgi.py

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    Listen 8080

    <VirtualHost *:8080>


        Alias /static /home/pep_web/protocol/static
        <Directory /home/pep_web/protocol/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        <Directory /home/pep_web/pep_learn>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess pep_web python-path=/home/pep_web:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup pep_web
        WSGIScriptAlias /pep_learn  /home/pep_web/pep_learn/wsgi.py

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName mypepapp.com


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    </VirtualHost>
```

Recently, I have purchased a domain name for second link through "godady" 
I tried to configure domain name "www.mydomain.com" with second link but its not working can any one suggest me a suitable and simple way to access  my application like this:

```
 www.mydomain.com/pep_learn
```

Which is currently accessible like this :

```
93.188.167.63:8080/pep_learn
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a DNS A-record pointing to the IP of your server?

Comment: @Jesse Bakker Where i can find the DNS I am not sure How can I check this.

Comment: This should be done with your DNS provider, which is probably also godaddy

Comment: Sorry I am a bigginer so let me check this first, I am using VPS from Hostingers.com" and Static IP  is also provided by hostinger and  Doaming name from "Godaddy"

Comment: @JesseBakker Yes I got the DNS information from Godaddy Now How can I proceed

Comment: https://nl.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238